# Using my own kernel in libsvm

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, svm

I am currently developing my own kernel to use for classification and want to include it into libsvm, replacing the standard kernels that libsvm offers.

I however am not 100% sure how to do this, and obviously do not want to make any mistakes. Beware, that my c++ is not very good. I found the following on the libsvm faq-page:

> Q: I would like to use my own kernel. Any example? In svm.cpp, there
>   are two subroutines for kernel evaluations: k_function() and
>   kernel_function(). Which one should I modify ?  An example is "LIBSVM
>   for string data" in LIBSVM Tools.
>
> The reason why we have two functions is as follows. For the RBF kernel
>   exp(-g |xi - xj|^2), if we calculate xi - xj first and then the norm
>   square, there are 3n operations. Thus we consider exp(-g (|xi|^2 -
>   2dot(xi,xj) +|xj|^2)) and by calculating all |xi|^2 in the beginning,
>   the number of operations is reduced to 2n. This is for the training.
>   For prediction we cannot do this so a regular subroutine using that 3n
>   operations is needed. The easiest way to have your own kernel is to
>   put the same code in these two subroutines by replacing any kernel.

Hence, I was trying to find the two subroutinges k_function() and kernel_function(). The former I found with the following signature in svm.cpp:

```
double Kernel::k_function(const svm_node *x, const svm_node *y,
              const svm_parameter& param)
```

Am I correct, that x and y each store one observation (=row) of my feature matrix in an array and I need to return the kernel value k(x,y)?

The function kernel_function() on the other hand I was not able to find at all. There is a pointer in the Kernel class with that name and the following declaration

```
double (Kernel::*kernel_function)(int i, int j) const;
```

which is set in the Kernel constructor. What are i and j in that case? I suppose I need to set this pointer as well?

Once I overwrote Kernel::k_function and Kernel::*kernel_function I'd be finished, and libsvm would use my kernel to compare two observations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to break into the code of LIBSVM to use your own kernel, you can use the pre-computed kernel option (i.e., -t 4 training_set_file).

Thus, you can compute the kernel matrix externally as it suits you, store the values in a file and load the pre-computed kernel to LIBSVM. There's an explanation accompanied with an example of how to do this in the [README](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/README) file that you can find in LIBSVM tar ball (see in the **Precomputed Kernels** section *line 236*).

Comment: Hi! Yes, thanks, that is what I ended up doing. It is much easier, but potentially also much slower unfortunately :(